# Adding the values of a dictionary to a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

Hi I am having a bit of difficulty adding tuples which are the values of a dictionary I have extracted the tuples and need to added to an iterable item say an empty list. i.e.

```
path = [1,2,3,4]
pos = {1:(3,7), 2(3,0),3(2,0),4(5,8)}
h = []
for key in path:
     if key in pos:
     print pos[key]
     h.append(pos[Key])#Gives an error
```

Please how can i append the values in pos[key] into a h. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *list comprehension*:

```
h = [pos[key] for key in path if key in pos]
```

**Demo:**

```
print h
>>> [(3, 7), (3, 0), (2, 0), (5, 8)]
```

**Notes:**

- A dictionary should be declared like pairs of `key:value`. Your syntax is incorrect.
- Also, Python is case-sensitive so `key` is different than `Key`.